# How and why is ROW(A1) used in these nested INDEX, MATCH and SMALL function formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2003

In the following nested functions formulas, I do not understand why ROW(A1) is used or why it even works. Please refer to the picture and the 2 nested function formulas below. These nested functions produce the Category and Time Spent data on the right side of the picture using the data on the left side. The formula in the 'H' column returns the category title/description and the formula in the 'I' column returns the total time spent. These are ordered from smallest to highest "Time Spent" values.

From the inner most function of the nest, the small function returns the ROW(A1)th smallest number in the array of total time spent cells. The match function, I believe, then returns the column letter of where that value was found. The index function then displays the value in the column value returned by the match function and in the row specified by the array of cells. When you copy this nested function into each successive row, it increments the "A1" to "A2", "A3" and so on.

I thought the ROW function just returned the row number of a referenced cell and if that reference is left out, it defaults to the cell address that contains the ROW function. So why does ROW(A1) work here to change to the next nth smallest number to be found by the SMALL function in each successful row and formula???

H3 =INDEX($B$3:$F$3,MATCH(SMALL($B$2:$F$2,ROW(A1)),$B$2:$F$2,0))

I3 =INDEX($B$2:$F$2,MATCH(SMALL($B$2:$F$2,ROW(A1)),$B$2:$F$2,0))

[image]

Thanks!

VH

Comment: when you drag it down it becomes row(A2), row(A3) etc. Which translates to 2, 3, etc. Which makes the SMALL function return the 2nd smallest, 3rd smallest etc...

Comment: @MacroMarc, that looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply referring to the position in the named array in the small function. You are indicating position 1, first smallest.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! That makes total sense. It is more or less a trick use of the ROW function.....and a good one...:) Thanks to Teylyn for her original answer and the pictured spread sheet, pivot table, graph and forumlas...:)

Answer (score 1):

First, look at what the formula resolves to on its own:

```
=ROW(A1)
```

This becomes simply 1. When used in a formula intended to be 'dragged down', the relative reference on A1 means that A1 will become A2, A3, and so on. On the 4th time that this is used, it will be:

```
=ROW(A4)
```

This resolves to 4. This is a common method to 'iterate' the number in a formula (increase in value by 1, for each new time the formula is used). Then, look at the SMALL function:

```
=SMALL($B$2:$F$2,4)
```

This gives you the 4th smallest number in the checked portion of row 2. Because the $'s are present, these references do not change as the formula is dragged down.

It seems you understand the remainder of that formula, but as you can now see, the SMALL function now adequately finds the smallest number in row 2, then the 2nd smallest number, etc.